# Pandas DataFrame Transpose index and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows but at a much large scale

```
        Sample  Taxonomy Count
    0   1       A        1 
    1   1       B        2
    2   1       C        5
    3   1       D        7
    4   2       B        1
    6   2       D        3
    7   2       E        4
    8   2       F        5
```

The result I desire is as follows

```
    Taxonomy  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
    Sample 1: 1  2  5  7  NA NA NA  
    Sample 2: NA 1  NA 3  4  5  NA
```

Tried making taxonomy the index but I still have a copy of each taxonomy for each sample and still when I transpose that with DataFrame.transpose() It does not result in the desired dataframe.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Sample', columns='Taxonomy', values='Count')` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Sample', columns='Taxonomy', values='Count')
print (df)
Taxonomy    A    B    C    D    E    F
Sample                                
1         1.0  2.0  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2         NaN  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Sample','Taxonomy'])['Count'].unstack()
print (df)
Taxonomy    A    B    C    D    E    F
Sample                                
1         1.0  2.0  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2         NaN  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: Glad can help you.